# Getting 'npm unable to find package.json' file when trying to run nestjs project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, nestjs, npm-start

I am following a nestjs tutorial on YouTube, I had previously installed nodejs so I just installed nest through the @nest-cli command as suggested on the website on my default bash terminal. I am using VSCode as my code editor and when I ran 'npm run start:dev'. 'npm run start', I keep getting this set of errors.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Hussenat EttiBalogun\Learn Javascript/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hussenat EttiBalogun\Learn Javascript\package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:       
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hussenat EttiBalogun\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-03T15_50_56_442Z-debug-0.log
```

When I went through all the automatically installed files, I saw that VSCode was giving the error 'unable to load schema' on this link "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli" so I went into the settings > manage trusted domains, and added the path.
This was after I checked that it was openable in my browser. After restarting the workspace, I was still getting the main error but it was no error on loading the schema.
I also tried 'npm cache clean -f' and 'npm cache clean --force' and 'npm cache verify' when I thought the former didn't work. I then did 'rm -rf node_modules' and 'npm i' but still they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wasn't in the right folder. I created the project in an already made directory in my laptop, but I didn't change the directory to the project directory before running `npm run start:dev`.

Once I did:

```
cd {project-name}
npm run start:dev
```

It ran successfully.